# Python: Best way to create an indexable object without creating every element at each index

Tags: python, arrays, list

Suppose you have a list, but it's either too large (or cumbersome) to actually calculate and store each element of the list. Suppose you can calculate elements as needed based on their index or some other rule. What would be the best way to do this?

Below is one way to do this, but are there other ways? Is there a standard way to do this?

```
import bisect

class Squares:
    def __init__(self, len):
        self.len = len
    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return i ** 2

target = 20
squares = Squares(10)
i = bisect.bisect_left(squares, target) # Finds the index of the smallest square >= target
print(squares[i]) # 25, the smallest square >= 20
```

The benefit in this particular case is that we don't need to calculate and store a list of 10 squares; we just calculate some of the squares as needed. 10 squares is not much to calculate and store, but in general, the number of elements or the complexity involved in calculating each element could be prohibitive.

Comment: I have different ideas but whether they are useful would depend upon your actual application. Do you have one you can share? Or is this just theory?

Comment: What @AndrewGraham said, but also if you are going to do this computations it will be important to save them. I would recommend a ```dict```. This technique is using memoization (not a typo)

Comment: My current application is not substantial; it's just to ensure a leetcode solution runs in O(lgN) instead of O(N).

Problem:
https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/january-leetcoding-challenge-2021/579/week-1-january-1st-january-7th/3594/

Solution:
https://repl.it/@joseville/Leetcode-Kth-Missing-Positive-Number